# query to get groups of points that are, at least at certain distance between groups

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a problem that I know how to solve (more or less) using a regular programming language in a non-optimal but good enough way.
I want to get a list of groups of points that are within certain range inside each group, but that each group does not overlap with the rest.
For example, group of points A are at a distance of 1 or less, same for points in group B but all points in A are at least at 1.1 distance of all points in group B.

The way I would do this on a programming language (in a non optimal way as I said) will be to pick any point, find all points that are in a range of 1 or less (call it group A), then pick one point that is not in that group and find all points that are not on the group A and that are at a distance of 1 or less call it group B. Loop again but now taking into account groups A and B.

Also it's worth mention that some points will have a flag to mark them as processed (previously grouped and that group saved), they should be ignored. Hopefully this that may speed up the query when several groups already exist.

I'm not sure if this is a task that can be accomplished within SQL in a single query or if I would be better to extract the data from the database and make another query with the new parameters.

My points are multi-dimensional (vectors of 128). But for simplicity this are some example ones:

```
id |x                    |y                     |z                     |
---|---------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
  1| -0.03909766674041748|   0.03122374415397644|   0.02698654681444168|
  2| -0.09763473272323608|   0.04069424420595169|   0.11512677371501923|
  3|-0.040237002074718475|    0.0678766518831253|   0.03919816389679909|
  4| -0.10432711988687515|   0.07187126576900482|   0.10971983522176743|
  5|  -0.1513511687517166|   0.07631294429302216|   0.05949840694665909|
  6|  -0.1276567280292511|   0.11543292552232742|   0.06757785379886627|
```

A query that I often use to find closest (very simplified points is this:

```sql
SELECT id, sqrt(
    power(X - -0.10434776544570923, 2) + 
    power(Y - 0.08688679337501526, 2) 
    ) AS distance 
FROM points
HAVING distance < 0.5
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

I'm not sure how the output data would look on a tabular form, but Ideally I want something like this:

```
ref_point | point_ids
----------|-------------
    2     | 12, 15, 16, 255, 85
    6     | 8, 12, 55, 44
```

Where ref_point is a point id that is at <1 of distance of all the points on it's group

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: I don't understand.  You might have distances such as 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5.  What groups would these be?

Comment: Groups will be by distance, 0.5, 1.5 is only used to calculate if they should be within the group or not.